# How to have double quotes only on embedded comma String in csv using CSVWriter?

Tags: java, spring, csv, apache-camel, opencsv

This is my expected result format in the output csv:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
monica,chandler,"rachel,ross",joey
```

My current results:

Strategy1:

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("D:/new.csv"));
String[] headers = new String[] { "header1", "header2", "header3", "header4"};    
String[] arr = new String[] { "monica", "chandler", "rachel,ross", "joey"};


result:
"header1","header2","header2","header4"
"monica","chandler","rachel,ross","joey"
```

Strategy2:

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("D:/new.csv"), CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
    String[] headers = new String[] { "header1", "header2", "header3", "header4"};    
    String[] arr = new String[] { "monica", "chandler", "rachel,ross", "joey"};


result:
header1,header2,header2,header4
monica,chandler,rachel",ross,joey
```

Can anyone suggest to me how to achieve this using OpenCSV framework's CSVWriter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CsvWriter::writeNext` method which also takes a `boolean` to indicate whether to use quotes always, or only when needed.

From the [documentation](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/AbstractCSVWriter.html#writeNext-java.lang.String:A-boolean-):

> *`applyQuotesToAll` - True if all values are to be quoted. False applies quotes only to values which contain the separator, escape, quote, or new line characters.*

An example:

```java
try (CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("new.csv"))) {
    String[] headers = new String[]{"header1", "header2", "header3", "header4"};
    String[] arr = new String[]{"monica", "chandler", "rachel,ross", "joey"};
    csvWriter.writeNext(headers, false);
    csvWriter.writeNext(arr, false);
}
```

The results:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
monica,chandler,"rachel,ross",joey
```

Comment: Thanks, @andrewjames, I was struggling to achieve this using the constructor way.