# Reading Multiple value column in csv file

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

I have a csv file with this columns:

```
imdb_title_id,title,original_title,year,date_published,genre,duration,country,language,director,writer,production_company,actors

tt0000009,Miss Jerry,Miss Jerry,1894,1894-10-09,Romance,45,USA,None,Alexander Black,Alexander Black,Alexander Black Photoplays,"Blanche Bayliss, William Courtenay, Chauncey Depew"
```

The question is how do i read the actors column as a single string value, this is my code so far:

```
    public void cargarDatos(){
        String fileName = "src/IMDb movies.csv";
        Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);
        try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile)){
            String line = reader.readLine();
            line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                String[] atrributes = line.split(",");

                Movie newMovie = new Movie(attributes);

                movieList.add(newMovie);

                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't read the actors as a single string because you are using a comma as a delimiter for each actor. Use a different delimiter. Maybe something like: `Blanche Bayliss:William Courtenay:Chauncey Depew`. And get rid of the quotes around the actors as they mean nothing to the file reader. Another option is to use a real CSV reader class, that will handle text in quotes.  Search the web using `csvreader` or `csvparser` to find a class.

Comment: Or you know you should have 13 columns. If you have more then that then the extra items in the array are the actors. So you would recombine all items from 13 and up into your actor string.

Comment: Definitely use a library. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592176/how-to-have-double-quotes-only-on-embedded-comma-string-in-csv-using-csvwriter) is a very simple example, just to give you an idea. It writes a file, rather than reads one, but it shows the benefits of using a decent CSV library.

Answer (score 0):

`String[] atributos = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);`